# Jasper report generation using VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, jasper-reports

I want to call Jasper Reports via VB.net.Is this possible?

Thank you,
hm

Answer (score 1):

Yep.

<strike>JasperReports.NET</strike> - .NET port of Jasper Reports

Edit:

Looks like the original project disappeared from the site. Another option: [Moonstone](http://jasperforge.org/projects/moonstone-.netwebservicesclient)

Comment: Hi there, would you refer for good sample sites on this. Thanks